# Some Activities Crash in Api 10 Android Emulator

Tags: java, android

I'm just about at the end of development for my first android app but it crashes when I test it on an android emulator using api 10. The main activity starts just find but other activities crash. I get a thread exception error and I don't have the source for to track it down by source code. So my question is should I publish my app anyways? Because it seems to work fine on the high APIs. And I from the android statics distribution page API 10 only account for 13.5% of the devices visited by the google play store and about 14.5% if you add in the rest of the APIs below 10.

Comment: please post Logcat about the crash

Comment: You should either fix that or set `minSdk` to 11 if you publish this app.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: I found the errors in logcat, it was issues with typeface and setText color